# Python; Tkinter; using canvas in multiple modules

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm interested in next thing: Can we use the same canvas object in multiple programs? For example: I have module called 'canvas' with the following code:

```
from tkinter import*

window = Tk()
window.geometry("600x200")
window.configure(background='black')
C = Canvas(window)
C.configure(background='brown')
C.config(width=600,height=200)
C.create_oval(10, 10, 50, 50,fill='black',outline = 'white')
C.place(relx=.0, rely=.0)
window.mainloop()
```

And now I have another program , where I want to use the same canvas, and draw second oval:

```
from canvas import C

C.create_oval(80, 10, 120, 50,fill='black',outline = 'white')
```

This code draws nothing on the screen, canvas appears just like before; there's no second oval. So is this possible to do?

Comment: Problem is you create the second oval _after_ the mainloop. Try to create a function in your first module that creates the canvas, but does not call `mainloop`, then "finish" the canvas in the second module and start the mainloop.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I tried with `window.update()` in the second module

Comment: could you remove the mainloop from your module? after all, a single module should not show/execute anything, it should provide code. you could write `if __name__=="__main__": window.mainloop()`, so the mainloop does not start if you import your module.